# Freebase MQL query to get all info about a specific date

Tags: freebase, mql

I'm wondering if it is possible to get all info about a specific date from Freebase.

I can easily retrieve info about a date giving a specific topic, for example, to grab all persons of interest who were born on a specific date:

```json
[{
  "type":"/people/person",
  "limit":1000,
  "sort":"name",
  "name":null,
  "guid":null,
  "timestamp":null,
  "/people/person/date_of_birth":"1955-02-24"
}]
```

Is it possible to grab all types?  I'm after things like people born on that date (which I have), major events (start of a war, assassination of a person of interest, etc), and so on.

Essentially I want to match all fields that are dates and return the full information about that entry, regardless of `type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reflection](http://mql.freebaseapps.com/ch03.html#reflection) is what you need here:

```json
[{
  "/type/reflect/any_value": [{
    "type": "/type/datetime",
    "value": "1955-02-24",
    "link": {
      "source": {
        "id": null
      },
      "master_property": null
    }
  }]
}]
```

A couple of notes on that: the MQL manual I've linked to is somewhat bitrotted in its details but is still the best documentation that exists on MQL. Secondly, there's what I'm pretty sure is in MQL bug if you use `"*": null` or more specifically `"target_value": null` in the `link` clause above which makes it ignore the outer value you specified... so don't do that :-)

Comment: Hmm, that gives me: `{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Type /type/datetime does not have property master_property",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "/type/reflect/any_value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Type /type/datetime does not have property master_property"
 }
}`

Comment: Replaced `master_property` with `'*' : null` and now I have a ton of data :)

Comment: Works for me - I think you may have messed up the bracketing somewhere?

Comment: I suspect this will miss values which have a time specified.  They're pretty rare, but if you want to include them, you may need to use "v1:value>=":"date","v2:value<=":"date+1"

Comment: @TomMorris yeah, I was thinking about that as well. Unfortunately, putting any prefix on the "value" key seems to cause the query to timeout, even without a second "value" key. I don't know if that's just Freebase playing up or an MQL bug though...